# Merges variable with itself from group_vars | Ansible

Tags: ansible, dns, devops

I have a variable called "DNS". This variable is written in /defaults folder of the role and in inventory/group_vars.

```
# roles/defaults/main.yml
  
  DNS:
    - "0.0.0.0" # Those IPs are for the example
    - "0.0.0.1"
```

```
# inventory/group_vars/special_group.yml
  DNS:
    - "0.0.0.2" # Those IPs are for the example
    - "0.0.0.3"
```

The point is when role is being executed in special_group hosts it writes only DNS of the special_group.yml which is OK. But when it goes to other hosts role writes DNS from both defaults/main.yml and special_group.yml while I need DNS captured only in defaults/main.yml.

This command is being executed in the role to rewrite DNS

```
 - name: Change DNS
   nmcli:
     conn_name: "{{ connection_name }}"
     dns4: "{{ DNS }}"
     state: present
```

Comment: Your playbook worked properly on `ansible [core 2.13.3]`

Comment: I don't know. Have same version. Did it twice on different VM's not included in special_group. And still have 4 DNS

Comment: Take a look at my [demo](https://i.postimg.cc/BQLYHQYQ/test.gif)

Comment: I'm really confused right now. Looks exactly same.

[Result of debug](https://postimg.cc/gwtnv1Ff)

[default/main.yml](https://postimg.cc/47zRJh5B)

[group_vars](https://postimg.cc/qtJ1t641)

Sorry for bluring, company private IPs

Comment: How does your inventory look like?

Comment: [Like this](https://postimg.cc/phw3GJKC)
There are no intersection of hosts in special_group with other groups. And so in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can close this question. It really works well, it was just my fault.

I forgot that I have added all of 4 DNS servers in group_vars/all.yml under the DNS variable.

Nevertheless, thank you [Khaled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13761535/khaled) for the advices and will to help.